# Limit axis movement after zooming in D3 v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two axes which movement is limited to zero tick in all four directions (with redrawChart(transform) function). It means, 0 tick is always visible.
But after zooming (mouse scroll or double click), I can't figure out the correct formula for the same constraint. 
I tried to use transform.k, but it didn't work.

How I can limit the movement of the axes to 0 tick, after zoom event?

```js
function init()
{
 class TrendChart {
    constructor(width, height, visual_margin, data_margin) {
        this.xlen  = 0;
  this.canvas_w = width;
  this.canvas_h = height;
  this.visual_margin = visual_margin;
  this.data_margin = data_margin;
   this.chart_height = height - 2*visual_margin;
  this.chart_width = width - 2*visual_margin;
  this.ctx;
  this.svg;
  this.y;
  this.x;
  this.axis_bottom;
  this.axis_left;
  this.g_axis_bottom;
  this.g_axis_left;
          // 192847     //'#142340'
  this.color_scheme = {odd_col_bg:'#192847', even_col_bg:'#142340', axis_color:'#ff0000', label_color:'#ffffff', 
       series:{'0':{stroke_style: '#00ffdd', fill_style: '#00ffdd'}, 
         '1':{stroke_style: '#ffaa00', fill_style: '#ffcc00'}}
        };

    }

    showBG() {
  var canvas = d3.select('#chart').append('canvas')
         .attr('width', this.canvas_w)
         .attr('height', this.canvas_h)
         .style('background-color','blue')
         .style('width', this.canvas_w+'px')
         .style('height', this.canvas_h+'px')
         .style('position','absolute')
         .style('top', 0)
         .style('left', 0);

  this.ctx = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

  this.svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
         .attr('width', this.canvas_w)
         .attr('height', this.canvas_h)
         .style('width', this.canvas_w+'px')
         .style('height', this.canvas_h+'px')
         .style('position','absolute')
         .style('top', 0)
         .style('left', 0)
         .call(d3.zoom()
         //.scaleExtent([1, 50])
         // .translateExtent([[-(this.canvas_w/2 - this.visual_margin), -(this.canvas_h/2 - this.visual_margin)]
         //     , [this.canvas_w*3/2 - this.visual_margin, this.canvas_h*3/2 - this.visual_margin]])
         .on("zoom", () => this.zoom_function(d3.event.transform)))
 }


 showAxis(y_minval,y_maxval, data_len){
  d3.selectAll(".axis").remove();

  this.y = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([y_minval-this.data_margin, y_maxval+ this.data_margin])
     .range([this.chart_height+this.visual_margin, this.visual_margin])
     //.nice();

  this.x = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([-(data_len-1), data_len-1])
     .range([this.visual_margin, this.chart_width+this.visual_margin])
     //.nice(); 

  this.axis_bottom = d3.axisBottom(this.x);

  this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("id", "xaxis")
    .attr("transform", 'translate(0,'+ (this.canvas_h-this.visual_margin) +')')
    .call(this.axis_bottom);

  var axis_bottom_ticks = this.axis_bottom.scale().ticks();
  var xaxis_stroke_width = 1;


  this.axis_left = d3.axisLeft(this.y);
  this.g_axis_left = this.svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "axis")
         .attr("id", "yaxis")
         .attr("transform", 'translate(' + this.visual_margin +', 0)')
         .call(this.axis_left);

  var yaxis_stroke_width = 1;

  this.g_axis_bottom = d3.select("#xaxis");
  this.g_axis_left = d3.select("#yaxis");

  this.setSizeOfAxisTick('x', 0, -1*this.chart_height);
  this.setSizeOfAxisTick('y', 0, this.chart_width);
 }

 showChart(data_len){
  this.showAxis(-1, 1, data_len);
 }


 redrawChart(transform){
  if(Math.abs(transform.x/transform.k)>(this.canvas_w/2 - this.visual_margin)){
     var new_transform = Math.floor(this.canvas_w/2) - this.visual_margin - 1;
     transform.x = transform.x>0 ? new_transform*transform.k: -1*new_transform*transform.k;
  }
  

  if(Math.abs(transform.y/transform.k)>(this.canvas_h/2 - this.visual_margin)){
     var new_transform = Math.floor(this.canvas_h/2) - this.visual_margin - 1;
     transform.y = transform.y>0 ? new_transform*transform.k: -1*new_transform*transform.k;
  }
  

  const scale_x = transform.rescaleX(this.x);
  const scale_y = transform.rescaleY(this.y);

  this.g_axis_bottom.call(this.axis_bottom.scale(scale_x));
  this.g_axis_left.call(this.axis_left.scale(scale_y));


  this.setSizeOfAxisTick('x', 0, -1*this.chart_height);
  this.setSizeOfAxisTick('y', 0, this.chart_width);
 }


 zoom_function(transform){
  this.ctx.save();
  this.redrawChart(transform);
  this.ctx.restore();
 }

 setSizeOfAxisTick(axis, number, size){
  var xaxis_element = document.getElementById(axis+'axis');
     var all_ticks = xaxis_element.querySelectorAll(".tick"); 
     var res = Array.from(all_ticks).find(v => Number(v.textContent) == Number(number));
     if(res)
      res.querySelector("line").setAttribute((axis=='x'?'y':'x')+'2', size);
 }
}//end class

///*********************************************************///
chart = new TrendChart(400, 200, 40, 0.1); 
chart.showBG();
chart.showChart(1113);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Trend Chart Test</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   .tick text {color: #ffffff !important;}
   .axis line {stroke: #ff0000 !important;}
   svg { shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script src="./trend.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```js
function init()
{
 class TrendChart {
    constructor(width, height, visual_margin, data_margin) {
        this.xlen  = 0;
  this.canvas_w = width;
  this.canvas_h = height;
  this.visual_margin = visual_margin;
  this.data_margin = data_margin;
   this.chart_height = height - 2*visual_margin;
  this.chart_width = width - 2*visual_margin;
  this.ctx;
  this.svg;
  this.y;
  this.x;
  this.axis_bottom;
  this.axis_left;
  this.g_axis_bottom;
  this.g_axis_left;
  this.xaxis_0_pos = width/2;
  this.yaxis_0_pos = height/2;

          // 192847     //'#142340'
  this.color_scheme = {odd_col_bg:'#192847', even_col_bg:'#142340', axis_color:'#ff0000', label_color:'#ffffff', 
       series:{'0':{stroke_style: '#00ffdd', fill_style: '#00ffdd'}, 
         '1':{stroke_style: '#ffaa00', fill_style: '#ffcc00'}}
        };

    }

    showBG() {
  var canvas = d3.select('#chart').append('canvas')
         .attr('width', this.canvas_w)
         .attr('height', this.canvas_h)
         .style('background-color','blue')
         .style('width', this.canvas_w+'px')
         .style('height', this.canvas_h+'px')
         .style('position','absolute')
         .style('top', 0)
         .style('left', 0);

  this.ctx = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

  this.svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
         .attr('width', this.canvas_w)
         .attr('height', this.canvas_h)
         .style('width', this.canvas_w+'px')
         .style('height', this.canvas_h+'px')
         .style('position','absolute')
         .style('top', 0)
         .style('left', 0)
         .call(d3.zoom()
         //.scaleExtent([1, 50])
         // .translateExtent([[-(this.canvas_w/2 - this.visual_margin), -(this.canvas_h/2 - this.visual_margin)]
         //     , [this.canvas_w*3/2 - this.visual_margin, this.canvas_h*3/2 - this.visual_margin]])
         .on("zoom", () => this.zoom_function(d3.event.transform)))
 }


 showAxis(y_minval,y_maxval, data_len){
  d3.selectAll(".axis").remove();

  this.y = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([y_minval-this.data_margin, y_maxval+ this.data_margin])
     .range([this.chart_height+this.visual_margin, this.visual_margin])
     //.nice();

  this.x = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([-(data_len-1), data_len-1])
     .range([this.visual_margin, this.chart_width+this.visual_margin])
     //.nice(); 

  this.axis_bottom = d3.axisBottom(this.x);

  this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("id", "xaxis")
    .attr("transform", 'translate(0,'+ (this.canvas_h-this.visual_margin) +')')
    .call(this.axis_bottom);

  var axis_bottom_ticks = this.axis_bottom.scale().ticks();
  var xaxis_stroke_width = 1;


  this.axis_left = d3.axisLeft(this.y);
  this.g_axis_left = this.svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "axis")
         .attr("id", "yaxis")
         .attr("transform", 'translate(' + this.visual_margin +', 0)')
         .call(this.axis_left);

  var yaxis_stroke_width = 1;

  this.g_axis_bottom = d3.select("#xaxis");
  this.g_axis_left = d3.select("#yaxis");

  this.setSizeOfAxisTick('x', 0, -1*this.chart_height);
  this.setSizeOfAxisTick('y', 0, this.chart_width);
 }

 showChart(data_len){
  this.showAxis(-1, 1, data_len);
 }


 redrawChart(transform){
  var new_xaxis_0_pos = this.xaxis_0_pos*transform.k+transform.x;
  var new_yaxis_0_pos = this.yaxis_0_pos*transform.k+transform.y

  //console.log(new_xaxis_0_pos, new_yaxis_0_pos);

  if(new_xaxis_0_pos<this.visual_margin+1){
   transform.x = this.visual_margin-this.xaxis_0_pos*transform.k+1;
  }
  else if(new_xaxis_0_pos>this.canvas_w-this.visual_margin-1){
   transform.x = this.canvas_w-this.visual_margin-this.xaxis_0_pos*transform.k-1;
  }

  if(new_yaxis_0_pos<this.visual_margin+1){
   transform.y = this.visual_margin-this.yaxis_0_pos*transform.k+1;
  }
  else if(new_yaxis_0_pos>this.canvas_h-this.visual_margin-1){
   transform.y = this.canvas_h-this.visual_margin-this.yaxis_0_pos*transform.k-1;
  }
   
      

  const scale_x = transform.rescaleX(this.x);
  const scale_y = transform.rescaleY(this.y);

  this.g_axis_bottom.call(this.axis_bottom.scale(scale_x));
  this.g_axis_left.call(this.axis_left.scale(scale_y));


  this.setSizeOfAxisTick('x', 0, -1*this.chart_height);
  this.setSizeOfAxisTick('y', 0, this.chart_width);
 }


 zoom_function(transform){
  this.ctx.save();
  this.redrawChart(transform);
  this.ctx.restore();
 }

 setSizeOfAxisTick(axis, number, size){
  var xaxis_element = document.getElementById(axis+'axis');
     var all_ticks = xaxis_element.querySelectorAll(".tick"); 
     var res = Array.from(all_ticks).find(v => Number(v.textContent) == Number(number));
     if(res)
      res.querySelector("line").setAttribute((axis=='x'?'y':'x')+'2', size);
 }
}//end class

///***********************************************************************************///
chart = new TrendChart(400, 200, 40, 0.5); 
chart.showBG();
chart.showChart(8113);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Trend Chart Test</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   .tick text {color: #ffffff !important;}
   .axis line {stroke: #ff0000 !important;}
   svg { shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script src="./trend.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```